# Authorization refused for guest

Tags: office-365, authentication

I recently created a Sharepoint site for my company. We want to use this website for our internal users and for guests.
There's no problem for internal users, for the guests, I sent them an email through Sharepoint (with the "Share" panel). For some of them, they were able to connect to the website without any problem.
But for others, they can't! When I check the authorization, I have a strange response, here's a printscreen :
[image]
As you can see, he got the correct authorizations but just beneath, I everything is "refused".
Do you know where I can find any information about these restrictions?

Have a good day,

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

You could check in your Central Administration if there is a Deny-Policy set on your Web Application. If there is a policy that applies to any of your guest-users, they would not be allowed to access the site - regardless of the permissions set on site-level.

On Office 365, I guess you can change these settings in the SharePoint-Admin-Center Sitecollection-Administration-panel to allow sharing to external users (see pictures).

[image: sharing]

[image: sharing2]

Unfortunately I only have a german SharePoint-365, but I hope the screenshots are helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. I still have all the "refused" everywhere